# A race condition when using Redis command incr and expire

Tags: redis, increment, race-condition

Based on the redis document: http://redis.io/commands/incr

In the paragraph Pattern: Rate Limiter 2
A shorter version code:

```
value = INCR(ip)

IF value == 1 THEN
  EXPIRE(ip, 1)
```

It's claimed there's a race condition to make EXPIRE never executes. Which means the value of ip can bounces from 0 to 2 some way.

However in my thoughts, since Redis is single thread and INCR is a primitive command, it shouldn't be atomic itself? Even if 2 clients do the INCR at almost the same time, how could them both retrieve 0 or both retrieve 2?

Comment: See also [What is the race condition for Redis INCR Rate Limiter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49251938/704244)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Imagine that you drop connection to redis server after `INCR` command was already executed but before `EXPIRE` was executed. In this case you never execute `EXPIRE` becouse as next call of code gives your value > 1. In redis documentation the term **race condition** used. But it is not successful term. A more correct term is **imperfect algorithm**. So this case not about race condition between 2 or more clients but about special cases in real world. Server connection loss for example.

Comment: I am also doing incr and then expire ... is there any way to prevent this? like atomic incr and expire... is lua script the only option?

Answer (score 14):

It is still possible to achieve what you want in a atomic way: you can use the [EVAL](http://redis.io/commands/eval) command.

`EVAL` is used to execute a script written in Lua inside the Redis server, the best part of it is that this script is executed like a single atomic operation.

The following script can be used with this purpose:

> local v = redis.call('INCR', ARGV[1]) if v == 1 then redis.call('EXPIRE', ARGV[1], ARGV[2]) end return v

The logic is really simple: We are storing the return value of a `INCR` command into a variable labeled v, then we check if v value is 1 (first increment) if it is, we call the command `EXPIRE` for that key and then we return the value of v. The ARGV[...] are the parameters passed to the script, ARGV[1] is the key name and ARGV[2] is the timeout in seconds for the given key.

Example using this script:

> > eval "local v = redis.call('INCR', ARGV[1]) if v == 1 then redis.call('EXPIRE', ARGV[1], ARGV[2]) end return v" 0 my_key 10
>
> (integer) 1
>
> > eval "local v = redis.call('INCR', ARGV[1]) if v == 1 then redis.call('EXPIRE', ARGV[1], ARGV[2]) end return v" 0 my_key 10
>
> (integer) 2
>
> > get my_key
>
> "2"

[wait 10 seconds]

> > get my_key
>
> (nil)

Comment: I knew this solution, simply curious about the original question I posted. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

I met the same question, what about this :
value = INCR(ip)
IF [ value == 1 || PTTL(ip) == -1 ]THEN
  EXPIRE(ip, 1)

If 2 clients do the PTTL at almost the same time, get -1 ,and set expire at almost same time