# What is the race condition for Redis INCR Rate Limiter 2?

Tags: redis, rate-limiting

I have read the INCR documentation [here](https://redis.io/commands/incr) but I could not understand why the Rate limiter 2 has a race condition.

In addition, what does it mean by `the key will be leaked until we'll see the same IP address again` in the documentation?

Can anyone help explain? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are talking about the following code, which has two problems in multiple-threaded environment.

```
1. FUNCTION LIMIT_API_CALL(ip):
2. current = GET(ip)
3. IF current != NULL AND current > 10 THEN
4.     ERROR "too many requests per second"
5. ELSE
6.     value = INCR(ip)
7.     IF value == 1 THEN
8.         EXPIRE(ip,1)
9.     END
10.    PERFORM_API_CALL()
11.END
```

> the key will be leaked until we'll see the same IP address again

If the client dies, e.g. client is killed or machine is down, before executing `LINE 8`. Then the key `ip` won't be set an expiration. If we'll never see this `ip` again, this key will always persist in Redis database, and is leaked.

> Rate limiter 2 has a race condition

Suppose key `ip` doesn't exist in the database. If there are more than `10` clients, say, `20` clients, execute `LINE 2` simultaneously. All of them will get a `NULL current`, and they all will go into the `ELSE` clause. Finally all these clients will execute `LINE 10`, and the API will be called more than `10` times.

This solution fails, because these's a time window between `LINE 2` and `LINE 3`.

**A Correct Solution**

```
value = INCR(ip)
IF value == 1 THEN
    EXPIRE(ip, 1)
END
IF value <= 10 THEN
    return true
ELSE
    return false
END
```

Wrap the above code into a `Lua` script to ensure it runs atomically. If this script returns `true`, perform the API call. Otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! However, I still have a question. So given that situation, in your correct solution, if there were `20` clients connect to it, and the current value is `NULL`, wouldn't each of them increment the value to 1 and as a result, returning `true` back?

Comment: Yes, all of them will increment the value. However, all the them also do `PERFORM_API_CALL`. So the API will be called more than `10` times in a second. After that, any subsequent request will find `value` has been set to `20`, and will not call the API any more.

Comment: I see, can I assume that the increment operations will definitely increase the value? So even when there are `20` clients simultaneously sent the requests, the increment value will increase to `20` rather than overwrite to `1`?

Comment: Yes, the `value` will be `20`.